# Deadlock with yes command

Tags: apt, expect

I have a script called `setup.sh`:

```
. install.sh && . tolinux.sh && . startn.sh && . startm.sh
```

This is `install.sh`:

```
yes | sudo apt-get update
yes | sudo apt-get install default-jdk
yes | sudo apt-get install expect
sudo apt-get install lftp

cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/

/usr/bin/expect <<END_SCRIPT
spawn make install
expect "Please enter the login/email*" { send "Username\r" }
expect "Please enter the password for user*" { send "password\r" }
expect "Please enter an update interval*" { send "30\r" }
expect "Do you wish to run something at successful update*" {send "N\r" }
END_SCRIPT
```

This is how I run the whole thing in the terminal:

```
. setup.sh
```

The `yes` command causes problem somewhere within the first two lines. I know both of those installs ask for confirmation. What happens is output similar to this:

```
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
ySelecting previously unselected package libdatrie1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libdatrie1_0.2.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdatrie1:amd64(0.2.8-1) ...
[several similar lines]
Selecting previously unselected package libpango-1.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpango-1.0-0_1.36.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (1.36.3-1ubuntu1) ...
_
```

(last underscore is where cursor keeps blinking)

I'm guessing that `yes` command has somehow interrupted the install, but I don't understand why or how...

Any ideas?

Comment: For your purpose, you probably should be sending the word yes (`echo yes`) instead of invoking the command `yes`

Comment: Odd, because rather than an interruption it looks like `apt-get` hung.

Comment: `echo y` worked for me. I can swap the install order and automate the rest with the `expect` command...

Comment: Why are you sourcing the scripts (`. script.sh`) instead of running them (`./script.sh`)?

Comment: I tried `./script.sh`, but that didn't work so I did it this way. Did I do something wrong? Because as long as all scripts execute one after another, I'm happy, whatever the method... I wanted to emulate the user punching them into terminal one after another.

Comment: I didn't know that... So the command would be `sudo apt-get -y install something`?

Comment: The proper solution would be to do this using native `apt-get` features. `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y default-jdk`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from `man apt-get`

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an
       undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or
       removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

have you tried ?

**edit**

my proposal for install.sh

```
 sudo apt-get -y update
 sudo apt-get -y install default-jdk
 sudo apt-get -y install expect
 sudo apt-get install lftp

 # rest unchanged
```

Comment: The problem is that installation of man also requests for (Y/N) input, which I can't automate, so that isn't what I want. I tried swapping the order to (first) install expect with the yes command and the rest with expect, but then yes blocks the expect install...

Comment: @Karlovsky120 no, archemar's point is that `apt-get` already has an option to automatically answer yes to prompts. Since you seem to be using `yes` for `apt-get` only, you can use the provided `-y` option instead of `yes`.